# List All Custom Post Types Posts in Nav Menu Dynamically

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, navigation

Ive successfully added all posts (of a custom post type) to my wordpress menu using this method: https://codeseekah.com/2012/03/05/list-all-posts-in-wordpress-navigation-menu/

Everything is working great. Unfortunately I get this error when saving the menu in wp admin:
"**The given object ID is not that of a menu item.**"
I get a long list of like 20 of them (one error for each menu item).

This is what I have in my functions file:

```
/**
 * List all posts in wp nav menu
 * @link https://codeseekah.com/2012/03/05/list-all-posts-in-wordpress-navigation-menu/
 * @param  [type] $items [description]
 * @param  [type] $menu  [description]
 * @param  [type] $args  [description]
 * @return [type]        [description]
 */
/* take care of the urls */
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'services_menu_filter', 12, 3 );
function services_menu_filter( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    /* alter the URL for cpt-archive objects */

    $menu_order = count($items); /* Offset menu order */
    $child_items = array();

    foreach ( $items as &$item ) {
        if ( $item->title != '##services##' ) continue;
        $item->url = '/services/';
        $item->title = 'Services';

        foreach ( get_posts( 'post_type=services&numberposts=-1' ) as $post ) {
            $post->menu_item_parent = $item->ID;
            $post->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
            $post->object = 'custom';
            $post->type = 'custom';
            $post->menu_order = ++$menu_order;
            $post->title = $post->post_title;
            $post->url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
            /* add children */
            $child_items []= $post;
        }
    } 
    return array_merge( $items, $child_items );
}
```

Any ideas to get rid of the wordpress menu error notifications? Everything works fine and I could live with it, but i dont want to throw off the client if/and when they see all the errors. Yes, I thought about hiding the errors with CSS, but thats just not good enough.

The web host is Kinsta.
I've tried adding the following to wp-config.php:

```
/** Memory Limit */
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're only adding the custom posts to the nav menu on the front-end and not on the back-end/*wp-admin*.

Therefore, you can use `is_admin()` to see if the hook `wp_get_nav_menu_items` is being called on the front-end or from an "admin" page such as the Appearance → Menus page.

So, replace this:

```
function services_menu_filter( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    /* alter the URL for cpt-archive objects */
```

..with this one:

```
function services_menu_filter( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $items;
    }

    /* alter the URL for cpt-archive objects */
```

Alternatively, replace this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'services_menu_filter', 12, 3 );
```

..with this one:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'services_menu_filter', 12, 3 );
}
```

Comment: That was it. I had to add this line right inside the function. **if ( is_admin() ) { return $items; }** Thank you.