# Critical Error customiser

Tags: php, functions

Ive successfully added all posts (of a custom post type) to my wordpress menu using this method:[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296543/list-all-custom-post-types-posts-in-nav-menu-dynamically)

Everything is working great. Unfortunately when I view the customiser, I get the "critical error on this website" message, it shows up on the preview pain, the admin navigation is visible however.

This is what I have in my functions file:

```
/**
* auto_child_page_menu
*/
/* Sub menu */
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'cpt_locations_filter', 12, 3 );

function cpt_locations_filter( $items, $menu, $args ) {
  if ( is_admin() ) { return $items; }
  $child_items = array(); 
  $menu_order = count($items); 
  $parent_item_id = 0;

  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array('history-menu', $item->classes) ){
        $parent_item_id = $item->ID;
    }
  }

  if($parent_item_id > 0){

      foreach ( get_posts( 'post_type=history&numberposts=-1' ) as $post ) {
        $post->menu_item_parent = $parent_item_id;
        $post->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
        $post->object = 'custom';
        $post->type = 'custom';
        $post->menu_order = ++$menu_order;
        $post->title = $post->post_title;
        $post->url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        array_push($child_items, $post); // If i comment out this line, the customiser returns as normal. 
      }

  }
  return array_merge( $items, $child_items );
}
```

When I comment out the line containing array_push, the customiser will return as normal. Makes me believe it is something to do with the child_items.

Anyone have any ideas how you would fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe array push can't deal with objects, use the original(faster) method in the code you copied from.

Comment: @t31os thanks for your suggestion, I updated using the original method `$child_items []= $post;`, however the problem remains. It is unusual how it is only the customiser that is affected, front end it renders as coded and no error is shown. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Odd that it would be a critical error vs no error at all over adding an item to an array. Start var_dump'ing your values / returning early and see what's up. This is debug / support terrority though, and really not suited to this site (it's not a tech support forum).